# Differential Equation$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{1}{x^{2}+y^{2}}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Please give me a hint to solve for $y$. Given,
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{1}{x^{2}+y^{2}}$$

I took $y=x\cdot\tan\theta$ but it was of no use.

Comment: Are you certain that there IS an exact solution that can actually be calculated?

Comment: Yeah,I am pretty sure about that.

Comment: If you note that $y'\neq 0$ for every $x$, you can try to solve the differential equation $x=x(y)$ assuming that it is smooth, and then find its inverse.

Comment: Please, see here: http://science.fire.ustc.edu.cn/download/download1/book/mathematics/Handbook%20of%20Exact%20Solutions%20for%20Ordinary%20Differential%20EquationsSecond%20Edition/c2972_fm.pdf 1.2.2, third equation, to solve equation $y'_x=y^2+x^2$. It's not much, but it is a start.

Comment: The only way I can think of is the numerical methods; or maybe Galerkin approximation.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that it's not solvable in closed form. By taking "the reciprocal" of both sides,
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y} = x^2 + y^2$$
I couldn't find a solution to this form either, and if you put it into Wolfram Alpha you get a really horrible looking answer for which I can't imagine a possible method.

Maybe someone who knows some advanced techniques will be able to help you more.

Comment: wolfram alpha uses Bessel function to represent the solution, which basically says nothing for Bessel function is defined as a solution of a class of ODEs.

Comment: Maybe with Laplace transform.